# Is it possible to inject HTML into $scope?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to do the following, when a user login then the header link will change to a dropdown with the username of current user.

When they logout the dropdown will change back to a link to Home Page.

Current code:

```
app.controller('menuCtrl', function ($rootScope, $location, Data) {
        $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {
            Data.get('session').then(function (results) {
                if (results.uid) {
                    console.log('Change Menu to Logged In Version');
                    $rootScope.menu = "<h3>Logged In</h3>";
                } else {
                    console.log('Changed Menu to Logged Out Version');
                    $rootScope.menu = "<h3>Logged Out</h3>";
                }
            });
        });
});
```

html

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" ng-controller="menuCtrl">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="navbar-header col-md-8">
        <a class="navbar-brand" rel="home">Freelancer Portal</a>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
          <li><a href="#">Back to Home</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div >
```

Any suggestions to improve in the code will be great too :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it that way (you will need to use [ngBindHtml](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)). I'd do it a little bit different.

How about this for your menuCtrl:

```
app.controller('menuCtrl', function ($rootScope, $location, Data) {
        $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {
            Data.get('session').then(function (results) {
                $rootScope.loggedIn = !!results.uid;
            });
        });
});
```

Then in your view:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" ng-controller="menuCtrl">

  <div ng-if="loggedIn">You are logged in!</div>
  <div ng-if="!loggedIn">You are not logged in!</div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="navbar-header col-md-8">
        <a class="navbar-brand" rel="home">Freelancer Portal</a>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
          <li><a href="#">Back to Home</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div >
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, i am still learning its hard haha :) Just a question though, when i do an ctrl+f5 i can see both versions for a split second? Is there anyway of preventing that?